# AFNetworking:- errorcode=-999 "cancelled" with https only

Tags: ios, alamofire, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I am calling an api with AFNetworking, It is working fine with HTTP request but when I am trying to hit with secure connection HTTPS, it returns the error code -999 "cancelled".

I know there any already many question for this error and it happens with the request is cancelled but my case is different. I am using the same request code for both HTTP and HTTPS.

I tried following things:-
 1. Add arbitrary load to true in info.plist
 2. Allowed invalid certificate with AFNetworking

Do anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks in advance